# Struct Array in C++ (Rad Studio 10.1 - App for Android)

Tags: android, arrays, c++builder

I have generally used struct arrays extensively for arrays in C++ for windows, with memory assigned via new and delete in the constructor and destructor respectively.

This my first Android App.

App crashes, ever since I changed my first Array from a simple
defined as float AccelZ[1000] in header file
used as AccelZ[i]

to a struct array defined in the header file and with new and delete in the FormCreate and FormDestroy events.
and used as AccelArray[i]->Z

Are struct arrays not used in Android? But if that were the case then I would have expected a compilation error.

Thanks

Edited now with example:

In header file:

```
const int MAXTIMESTEPS = 20000;  
struct AccelerationRecord  
{  
    float Z;  
};
```

Under Public:

```
AccelerationRecord* Acceleration[MAXTIMESTEPS];
```

In .cpp file under FormCreate   In Windows I would put this in the Constructor, but that did not work here for Android App (I'm new to Android Apps)

```
void __fastcall TTabbedwithNavigationForm::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{  
    for (int i; i < MAXTIMESTEPS; i++)  
      Acceleration[i] = new AccelerationRecord;  
>>snip other code    
}
```

Under FormDestroy (used to put this in destructor in Windows App)

```
void __fastcall TTabbedwithNavigationForm::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)  
{  
    for (int i; i < MAXTIMESTEPS; i++)  
      delete Acceleration[i];  
}
```

later in app, when used for the first time as

```
if (MotionSensor1->Sensor-
>AvailableProperties.Contains(TCustomMotionSensor::TProperty::AccelerationZ))  
{  
lbAccelerationZ->Text = lbAccelerationZ->Text.sprintf(L"Acceleration Z: %6.2f",MotionSensor1->Sensor->AccelerationZ+1);  
Counter += 1;  
Acceleration[Counter]->Z = MotionSensor1->Sensor->AccelerationZ+1;  
//crashes at this line in debug mode  
>> snip other code  
}
```

Comment: Structs and Arrays in C++ work exactly the same on Android as they do on any other platform.  Any errors you are encountering are due to you misusing them in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all:

```
for (int i; i < MAXTIMESTEPS; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i=0; i < MAXTIMESTEPS; i++)
```

with uninitialized `i` you can access the array out of the bounds causing crashes. The same goes for your:

```
Counter += 1;
```

I see not bound checking nor init so god knows what the value of `Counter` is.

second I am more used to this:

```
// "globals"
const int MAXTIMESTEPS = 20000; 
struct AccelerationRecord  
    {  
    float Z;  
    };  
AccelerationRecord* Acceleration=NULL;

// init
Acceleration = new AccelerationRecord[MAXTIMESTEPS];

// here do your stuff on AccelerationRecord[i]
AccelerationRecord[7].z=-1.5;

// exit
delete[] Acceleration;
```

single `new/delete[]` is much better than call it for each record for two reasons. First you stress less the memory manager (less overhead) and second this way you got continual memory block and remember just single pointer for the same stuff instead of `20000` using less memory and have faster and linear access...